# Rotating sprite generate artifacts

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, pyglet

I try to rotate a simple sprite with this code:

```
test_img = pyglet.resource.image('img.png')
self.test_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=test_img,x=300,y=400, batch=self.main_batch)

def update(self, dt):
    self.test_sprite.rotation -= float(100 * dt)
```

it works great, but I see artifact while it rotates, see the picture below, the left is a static image, the right is the one rotating:

[image]

I did a quick search and I find a discussion regarding it here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/5NiNT1vRHGw

But honestly I'm a newbie in pyglet and I don't get how should I amend the code above to remove the artifact.

**UPDATE:**

I fix the issue with the following code, but still not sure if it's the best way to do it:

```
test_img = pyglet.resource.image('img.png').get_texture()
glTexParameteri(test_img.target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(test_img.target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

self.test_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=test_img,x=300,y=400, batch=self.main_batch) 

def update(self, dt): 
   self.test_sprite.rotation -= float(100 * dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a coding problem, but that there's no safety margin around/between images in the texture (atlas) you use. You should a little margin around your picture (1 pixel should suffice), so that sample filtering doesn't bleed into the neighbour, clamps or wraps around.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I really don't know how to do what you suggest

Comment: @NiBE: Launch image manipulation program (Photoshop, GIMP, Paint.net), open image file, enlarge canvas, center the preexisting image, save image file. As I told: Not a coding but an arts department problem.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it right then,  I left 1pixel for each side of the sprite, centering the preexisting image, but I still see the artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Old question and no upvote? The issue is commonly referred to as "Texture bleeding".

If anyone is stumbling upon this and need a solution there is a plugin for GIMP that handles this as well as margins:

http://registry.gimp.org/node/26044